# Error while using tensorflow StagingArea along with dataset api

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Trying to incorporate tensorflow staging area along with dataset api.

```
compute_stage_put_op = compute_stage.put(iterator.get_next())
if compute_stage_put_op.type == 'Stage':
   compute_stage_ops.append(compute_stage_put_op)
```

Getting the below error after completing a few 100 steps.

```
ValueError: Fetch argument <tf.Operation 'group_deps' type=NoOp> 
            cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Operation name: 
            "group_deps" op: "NoOp")
```

Stack Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "timit_trainer.py", line 5, in 
    timit_trainer.train()
  File "/mnt/sdc/nlp/workspace/hci/nlp/mapc/core/model/model.py", line 43, in train
    hparams=self.hyper_params  # HParams
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_runner.py", line 218, in run
    return _execute_schedule(experiment, schedule)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_runner.py", line 46, in _execute_schedule
    return task()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py", line 625, in train_and_evaluate
    self.train(delay_secs=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py", line 367, in train
    hooks=self._train_monitors + extra_hooks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py", line 807, in _call_train
    hooks=hooks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 302, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 783, in _train_model
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 521, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 892, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 967, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 952, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1032, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitors.py", line 1196, in after_run
    induce_stop = m.step_end(self._last_step, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitors.py", line 356, in step_end
    return self.every_n_step_end(step, output)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitors.py", line 694, in every_n_step_end
    validation_outputs = self._evaluate_estimator()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitors.py", line 665, in _evaluate_estimator
    name=self.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 355, in evaluate
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 839, in _evaluate_model
    config=self._session_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/evaluation.py", line 206, in _evaluate_once
    session.run(eval_ops, feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 521, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 892, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 967, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 952, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1024, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 827, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1105, in _run
    self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 414, in **init**
    self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 236, in for_fetch
    return _DictFetchMapper(fetch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 374, in **init**
    for fetch in fetches.values()]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 374, in 
    for fetch in fetches.values()]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 234, in for_fetch
    return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 341, in **init**
    self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 341, in 
    self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 234, in for_fetch
    return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 341, in **init**
    self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 341, in 
    self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 242, in for_fetch
    return _ElementFetchMapper(fetches, contraction_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 278, in **init**
    'Tensor. (%s)' % (fetch, str(e)))
ValueError: Fetch argument  cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Operation name: "StagingArea_put"

Code:

def read(self, category: DatasetCategory, devices: list, proc_device: str, shuffle=False):

```
    batch_size = ds.BATCH_SIZE

    record_store_exists, record_store = self.__get_store_info(store_path=fu.join_path(self.store_dir, self.store_name + '_' + category.name + '.tfrecord'), create_new=False)
    logger.info('Reading records. category: {}, store_exists:{}, store;{}'.format(category.name, str(record_store_exists), record_store))
    if not record_store_exists:
        self.__process()
        record_store_exists, record_store = self.__get_store_info(store_path=fu.join_path(self.store_dir, self.store_name + '_' + category.name + '.tfrecord'), create_new=False)

    iterator_init_hook = SessionRunHook()
    map_fn = self.__parse_function

    gpu_copy_stage_ops = []
    gpu_compute_stage_ops = []

    def input_fn():

        file_names = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None], name='data_store')
        dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=file_names, buffer_size=2000000000)  # 2.0GB
        dataset = dataset.map(map_func=map_fn, num_parallel_calls=tf.constant(value=20000, dtype=tf.int32))
        if shuffle:
            dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=tf.constant(value=1000 * batch_size, dtype=tf.int64))

        dataset = dataset.repeat(None)  # Infinite iterations
        dataset = dataset.padded_batch(batch_size=tf.constant(value=batch_size, dtype=tf.int64), padded_shapes=([None, ds.NUM_INPUT_FEATURES], [], [None], []))

        iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
        iterator_init_hook.run_func = lambda session: session.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={file_names: [record_store]})

        gpu_copy_stage = StagingArea(dtypes=[tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32],
                                     shapes=[[batch_size, None, ds.NUM_INPUT_FEATURES], [batch_size], [batch_size, None], [batch_size]])

        gpu_compute_stage = StagingArea(dtypes=[tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32],
                                        shapes=[[batch_size, None, ds.NUM_INPUT_FEATURES], [batch_size], [batch_size, None], [batch_size]])

        features_dict = {}
        labels_dict = {}
        for index, device in enumerate(devices):
            with tf.device(proc_device):
                gpu_copy_stage_ops.append(gpu_copy_stage.put(iterator.get_next()))
            with tf.device(device):
                gpu_compute_stage_ops.append(gpu_compute_stage.put(gpu_copy_stage.get()))
                source, source_len, target, target_len = gpu_compute_stage.get()
                if ds.USE_WARP_CTC:
                    targets = []
                    for bi in range(batch_size):
                        targets.append(target[bi])
                    target = tf.concat(targets, axis=0)

                features_dict[device] = {'source': source, 'source_len': source_len}
                labels_dict[device] = {'target': target, 'target_len': target_len}

        return features_dict, labels_dict

    copy_stage_hook = StepOpsRunHook(ops=[gpu_copy_stage_ops], every_n_secs=1)
    compute_stage_hook = StepOpsRunHook(ops=[gpu_compute_stage_ops], every_n_steps=1)

    return input_fn, [iterator_init_hook, copy_stage_hook, compute_stage_hook]
```

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace for the `ValueError` plus the surrounding code for the `sess.run()` call that produced the error?

Comment: @mrry As requested please find the stack trace and code

Comment: @mrry
Please find the stack trace and code.